# responsive horizontal div height mismatch with youtube embedded

Tags: html, css, youtube

I'm having some problems with two horizontal divs maintaining the same height.
If both contain an image it's fine, but as soon as I try to embed a youtube video in one of the divs the height starts to mismatch as the viewport is decreased.

The code used is this:

```
<div class="IndexBanners">
<div class="bannerimages effect first">
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" frameborder="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/GfaiXgY114U" height="99%" width="100%">
</iframe>
</div>

<div class="bannerimages effect">
<a href="http://placehold.it"><img src="http://placehold.it/795x436"></a>
</div>
</div>
```

I've set up a fiddle so you can see the issue. 
https://jsfiddle.net/grvbc42o/1/

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Images are vertically aligned `baseline` by default and will leave a little bit of space at the bottom of their parent. If you give the image a `vertical-align` and change the height of the video to `100%`, they align properly.

```css
.IndexBanners {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.bannerimages {
  flex: 1 0 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: top;
}

@media (max-width:600px) {
  .IndexBanners {
    display: block;
  }
  .first {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    height: 0;
  }
  .first iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="IndexBanners">
  <div class="bannerimages effect first">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" frameborder="0" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/GfaiXgY114U" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
    <!--a href="http://placehold.it"><img src="http://placehold.it/795x436"></a-->
  </div>
  <div class="bannerimages effect">
    <a href="http://placehold.it"><img src="http://placehold.it/795x436"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That works perfectly. Thanks for the explanation on baseline.
One thing that puzzles me is why the video height is so small once it goes to 600px wide. The aspect ratio changes competely.

Comment: @StevePrice updated my answer, but that's outside of the scope of your question. If that's part of the question, be sure to add that to the question - ideally when you first ask, so that people don't answer if they don't know.

Comment: Cocker, It wasn't part of the question as I hadn't noticed it until I was reducing viewport looking at your original solution. Thanks for the update though, works as seamlessly as your original answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is the height defined for your image. I would suggest adding

```
style="height: 99% width=100%"
```

within your  tag.

If that does not work, I would suggest giving both the iframe and the img tags a mutual class, and defining desired height and width within the class. (and removing the height and width within the iframe tag.
Let me know if neither of those resolves your issue.

Comment: Site wide, images are given img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

Answer (score 0):

The `<iframe>` is definitely the issue here. They are a bear to work with, when trying to get them to behave responsively. Width is easy, height is not usually.

Following the [Intrinsic Ratio technique discussed by Ben Marshall](https://benmarshall.me/responsive-iframes/), I edited your Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/grvbc42o/3/. That very much so appears to achieve your goals.

Comment: Not at all. The two divs are not horizontally aligned anymore. The should only stack below 600px

Comment: Yeah... linked the wrong fiddle version..https://jsfiddle.net/grvbc42o/9/